# Prapatti-Yog (Surrender) is higher than Bhakti ,Karma & Gyan Yog?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, scripture, bhagavad-gita

**In Vaisnavs esepcially in Sri-vaisnavas,** belief that **Prapatti-Yog(Surrender) is higher than Bhakti, Karma and Gyan Yog.**

Lord Said lots of about Karma,Gyan and Bhakti yog in Bhagvad Gita but at last he said (Prapatti Yog)

> **sarva-dharmān parityajya
>      mām ekaṁ śaraṇaṁ vraja**
>
> **ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo
>   mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śucaḥ [18.66]**

Meaning:- Abandon all varieties of religion and just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.

As, we know It's Final Statement and absolute truth , we do'not need other scriptuers to support this statement and do'not need to dobut on Lord Statement.

**But,Still only for knowledge there are any scriptures which are support or mention the same statement in our Hinduism.Please Share your Idea.**

**Thanks..!!!**

Answer (score 1):

The Hare Krishna Maha-mantra has been prescribed by Lord Brahma in the Kalisantarana Upanishad (5; 6) of Krishna Yajur Veda as follows:

***hare krishna hare krishna krishna krishna hare hare | hare rAma hare rAma rAma rAma hare hare || 
iti shodashakam nAmnAm kali-kalmasha-nAshanam | nAtah pArataropayah sarva-vedeshu drishyate ||***

Lord Brahma instructs his son and disciple, Narada Muni as follows:

> “The sixteen words of the Hare Krishna Maha-mantra - (Hare Krishna Hare
>   Krishna Krishna Krishna Hare Hare Hare Rama Hare Rama Rama Rama Hare Hare) -
>   are especially meant for counteracting the sins of Kali-yuga. To save
>   oneself from the contamination of Kali-yuga there is no other
>   alternative, but to chant the Hare Krsna maha-mantra.After searching
>   through all the Vedic scriptures one cannot find a method of religion
>   for this age (Kali-yuga) so sublime as the chanting of the Hare Krishna 
>   maha-mantra.”

You have mistaken considering path of surrender to be higher than bhakti. Surrender is a limb of Bhakti Yoga.

The next [verse](http://www.vedabase.com/bg/18/67) states:

> This conﬁdential knowledge may never be explained to those who are not
>   austere, or devoted, or engaged in devotional service, nor to one who
>   is envious of Me.

In fact, in the very beginning Krishna has spoken to Arjuna that the qualification to get the revelation of Bhagavad Gita within the heart, as Arjuna got it, is through bhakti ONLY.

[BG 4.3](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/3)

> That very ancient science of the relationship with the Supreme is
>   today told by Me to you because you are **My devotee** as well as My
>   friend and can therefore understand the transcendental mystery of this
>   science.

To clarify any misconception or jugglery of grammar to show Bhakti as inferior to Gyana, etc or a part of it Krishna has spoken the following verses:

[BG 6.47](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/6/47)

> And of all yogīs, the one with great faith who always abides in Me,
>   thinks of Me within himself and renders transcendental loving service
>   to Me – he is the most intimately united with Me in yoga and is the
>   highest of all. That is My opinion.

[BG 11.55](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/11/55)

My dear Arjuna, he who engages in My pure devotional service, free from the contaminations of fruitive activities and mental speculation, he who works for Me, who makes Me the supreme goal of his life, and who is friendly to every living being – he certainly comes to Me.

Fruitive activities points to Karma Kanda and mental speculation to Gyana and Dhyana Yoga. Devotional service undoubtedly is Bhakti Yoga.

So there is no difference between Bhakti Yoga and Surrender. Surrender is the topmost limb of Bhakti Yoga. Surrendering by following the instructions of Lord Shri Krishna is Bhakti Yoga.

So I would recommend you to become well versed with Bhagavad Gita first. That is sufficient in itself in this age of Kaliyuga. Too many shastras means too much of jugglery as I often read here. That's why for Kaliyuga, Bhagavad Gita was delivered, personally spoken by the Lord Himself, right before it's start.

You can learn further by subscribing to free online course [Ultimate Self Realization Course](http://www.joincourse.com). It has 18000+ subscribers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40727/discussion-on-answer-by-ka-prapatti-yog-surrender-is-higher-than-bhakti-ka).